# How to Change App name and App icon of iOS app At run time?

Tags: ios

We are building an Generalised iOS app Product in Swift.

1. We need to change app icon and app name at run time. is this fusible in any way?
2. One Organisation is promising that he has command line tool that can help me to achieve point 1. is this possible?

We are new to iOS development society. So please help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/2806818-setalternateiconname for the icon ? "that he has command line tool " So that's when building/releasing then? If that's the case, I think you are interested in looking for "Targets".

Comment: Demo is here for icon https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/dynamically-change-the-app-icon-7d4bece820d2